# C++ Union member not initialized

Tags: c++, initialization, unions

I was just beginning my quest with unions when I found something weird

If I run this program

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    union myun{
    public:
    int x;
    char c;
    };

    int main()
    {
     myun y;
     //y.x=65;
      y.c='B';
     cout<<y.x;
    }
```

The output was some garbage value which doesnt change if change the value of y.c.
      Next I did this

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    union myun{
    public:
    int x;
    char c;

    };
     int main()
     {
      myun y;
      y.x=65;
      y.c='B';
      cout<<y.x;
     }
```

The output was as expected to be 66 because y.c='B' replaces the 65 by its ASCII value(66).
     Can anyone explain the first case?

Comment: Reading from one after setting the other is UB, IIRC.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually undefined behaviour to read from a union member that wasn't the last one written to.

You can do this if the items within the union are *layout-compatible* (as defined in the standard) but that's not the case here with an `int` and `char` (more correctly, it *could* be the case if those two types had similar bit widths, but that's not usually the case).

From the C++03 standard (superceded by C++11 now but still relevant):

> In a union, at most one of the data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the data members can be stored in a union at any time.

I think you may want to look into `reinterpret_cast` if you want to do this sort of overlaying activity.

---

In terms of what's actually happening under the covers in the first one, the hex value of the number output:

```
-1218142398 (signed) -> 3076824898 (unsigned) -> B7649F42 (hex)
                                                       ==
                                                       ^^
                                                       ||
                                       0x42 is 'B' ----++
```

should provide a clue. The `y.c='B'` is only setting the single *byte* of that structure, leaving the other three bytes (in my case) as indeterminate.

By putting in the `y.x=65` line before that point, it's setting all *four* bytes, with those three spare ones being set to zero. Hence they stay at zero when you set the single byte in the following assignment.

Comment: Not only is this undefined behavior because of of the rule about active members in a union, but if storing one member and reading another member were to access the value of the stored member then this would be a strict aliasing violation. Also, I don't see anything in the standard that mentions that objects of different types are layout compatible if they're the same width, so I don't think that if char and int were the same width that they'd be layout compatible.

Comment: `static_cast`? Did you mean `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: Sorry, David, you're absolutely right, fixed it. bames53, I didn't say that would make them layout_compatible, I said it _could._ It's _likely_ since both int and char are arithmetic types but I'm not sure it's guaranteed.

Comment: union is something Cpp can deprecate. Infact, std::variant is recommended over raw union. union is the most disastrous feature to use in C. I was using it in one of my apps and it caused a bad bad undefined behaviour. Reading the union member once I got false. reading it twice I got true. Even though the union member wasnt initialized to true. But initializing the union member solved that problem. But I will just f@@k unions.

Comment: @user13947194: so the solution to the bad effects of you not following the rules when using unions is to never use unions? Surely it would make more sense to use them properly, yes? Especially since (if I understand correctly what you're saying) arbitrary values in uninitialised variables is nothing to do with unions, the exact same thing can happen with an `int`. I do agree that variant is a nicer high-level alternative so we can agree on that.

Comment: In terms of deprecating (and presumably eventually removing) unions, I'm doubtful that would ever happen. It would break a *lot* of existing code. The only deprecation/removal I've seen was `gets()` from ISO C and that's because there's *no* way to use it safely (without possibility for buffer overflow). Since unions *do* have a safe use, they'll almost certainly remain. People don't *have* to use it, given the `variant` alternative.

Comment: @paxdiablo No it makes no sense. They are too hard to use. Cpp is already difficult and filled with undefined behaviour left right. Unions only add to the burden. And no it is not similar to using uninitialized int. You can read unitialized ints in any compiler you just get garbage/ left over value. reading unitialized union can cause your program to behave irrationally. such as being false when printed once, then true when printed twice. Note that struct p{union{...}}; p obj = {}; should be initialized to all zeros. Yet you get said irrational behaviour.

Comment: @paxdiablo and thats just a union with primitives and aggregate structs. unions with classes with constructors require placement new initialization and manual call to destructor. So I only use primitives/pointers to new in unions. Also note that the ability to read a variable without having to initialize it comes in handy. We are human and might fail to initialize our variables as code gets more and more complex. That doesnt mean your program should start acting irrational. Just print out garbage and I know. and remember struct p obj = {} is initialized to zeros. Thus any union member is zero?

Comment: @user13947194: I'm not sure you fully understand UB. The standard states that "if an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined" except for some very limited exceptions. It also states UB is "behavior for which this document imposes ***no*** requirements" (my emphasis), ranging from "ignoring the situation completely with ***unpredictable*** results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner". In other words, it's perfectly acceptable for an unitialised integer to give you a different value each time you use it.

Comment: And I'm not *certain* of this but I think `p obj = {}` does not start the lifetime of any of the union members. Without that, *none* of them can be accessed yet. It may fill the memory with zeros but that is not sufficient to make accessing a union member defined. In fact, I think an empty initialiser was invalid until C++23 (and there, no initialisation happens).

Comment: what is an empty initializer, {} ? No that is perfectly valid. And as I said i itializing an aggregate struct to {} zeros out the struct. So the only logical value to get from any union in the struct is zero. Any other value is irrational undefined behaviour. Now what in that you dont understand? Reading indeterminate int is undefined?? I never had my program behave irrational because of that; on any compiler.

Comment: @user13947194: The standard is quite clear. Reading an uninitialised variable is undefined behaviour in which anything can happen. You seem to be insisting that the "anything" must be somehow limited to "can be any value but must be the same value each time". That's not how UB works. An implementation is quite free to realise that you're reading an uninitialised value and not even bother going to the memory location to get it. It may just give you whatever happens to be in a register at that time. The quote for UB is "imposes no requirements", there's a reason I bolded that earlier.

Comment: On the union, the lifetime of a union members starts when you set it and ends when you set a different one. Setting the union (not it's members) to empty starts the lifetime of the first member (usually, but there are exceptions). So I was wrong to state that `p obj = {}` didn't start any lifetimes. But it only starts *one* member, you can't reliable use the other ones. My suggestion would be to look at the underlying code to see what's happening under the covers but the bottom line is you cannot rely on anything if you use UB.

Comment: But, of course, this is all very informative but actually has nothing to do the the question raised here. So I'll hold off further comments. If you want to keep going, I'm happy to move it to chat or you can open another question asking how it works. I don't doubt you'll get a lot of responses from other language lawyers as well :-)

Comment: If you haven't been like ChatGpt this conversation would end already. I already told you it was undefined behaviour. And I told you I am not comfortable with using unions because of that undefined behaviour. And I told you that all compilers I have used have well defined behaviour of uninitialized integral variables. (They simply return the garbage value. Garbage value is not persistent across program run).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you kinda explained the first case when you showed your understanding of the second case.

Initialising the character part only modifies one byte in a datatype that provides `int`.  Assuming 32-bit int, that means 3 bytes are still uninitialised...  Hence the garbage.

Here's the memory usage of your union:

```
              byte
           0  1  2  3
         +------------
myun::x  | X  X  X  X
myun::c  | X  -  -  -
```

When you set `x`, you set an integer, so all remaining bytes are initialised.  When you set `c`, you only modify a single byte.

Answer (score 1):

```
  y.c='B';
 cout<<y.x;
```

This has undefined behaviour. At any given time, union contains only one of its members. You cannot try to read the `int` member if it actually contains the `char` member. Because the behaviour of this is not defined the compiler is allowed to do what it wants with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Because `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char)`.

That is to say, an integer and a character take up different amounts of memory (in the average computer these days, int is 4 bytes, char is 1 byte). The union is only as large as it's largest member. Thus, when you set the char, you only set 1 byte of memory - the other 3 bytes are just random garbage.

Either set the biggest member of the union first, or do something like:

```
memset(&y, 0, sizeof(y));
```

to fill the entire union with zero.

Answer (score 1):

In a union, memory allocated is equal to the size of the largest member,which in your case is int i.e. 2 bytes in case of 16-bit compiler. All members use the same memory space to store their data, hence practically, only one type of member can be stored at a time.

When you assigned the value 'B' to the char member it stored 66 in its memory space of 1 byte.
Then you tried to output the value of the int member which however tried to compute a value by reading values from 2 bytes of the memory, hence you got a garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables (more specifically variables on the stack, i.e. having storage class "automatic") of POD type aren't initialised to anything when they are declared, so the 3 bytes (or 7 bytes on a 64-bit system) not affected by your assignment to `y.c` will contain random garbage.

Also note that the particular byte affected by the assignment to `y.c` depends on the endianness of the CPU, so this code will behave differently on different systems even if you initialise `y.x` before assigning to `y.c`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable y is of the union type, and the y's length is four bytes. For instance, y's memory layout is like this:

```
---------------------------------
| byte1 | byte2 | byte3 | byte4 |
---------------------------------
```

1) In the first program, the sentence  `y.c='B';` just set byte1, but byte2, byte3, byte4 are random values in the stack.

2) In the second program, the sentence y.x=65; set byte1 as 65 , the byte2, byte3, byte4 is zero. Then, the sentence `y.c='B';` set byte1 as the integer ASCII value of 'B', hence giving an output of 66.